# Where can I find specific details on how to deploy a Blazor app to IIS10 running on Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've taken and downloaded the Blazor course related solution found here:
[Git hub solution](https://github.com/claudiobernasconi/FinanceMentor)

And it works perfect from my development machine running from VS2019 but when deployed to IIS it exhibits the following: *Http Error: 401.2 - unauthorized*.
[image]

I've confirmed that there is no authentication in the C# code base.

I've followed this base article on how to configure IIS 10 (mine is on Win server 2019).
and I've downloaded and I'm using the latest runtime, hosting bundle etc. for .NET5:
[Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51588.blazor-deploying-an-application-on-iis-10.aspx)

I publish from VS2019, the .Server project and copied that "publish" file folder to the IIS server.

I can't determine what I've done wrong.

I've checked that the Hosting Bundle is listed for IIS:
[image]

Here's the site:

[image]

Here's the pool:

[image]

Here's the permission:

[image]

Here's the Auth:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the Authentication module of the site.

[image]

Enable Anonymous Authentication and disable other authentication. Then try to access it again.

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the Auth as suggested but it has no effect.  I'm still getting the same exact error as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the usage but I tried the "Authorization Rules" for the website and set it to Allow "All Users" which solved my issue.  Maybe it's IIS 10 but on pervious versions of IIS I never set this (not even looked at this) for any of my ASP.Net applications.
[image]